# Preload Image Without BuildContext

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to load images in Flutter in a function without access to a BuildContext?

Flutter can preload images with `precacheImage()` which requires a BuildContext and is inconvenient to use.

I would like to load images in the `initState()` method of a StatefulWidget which `precacheImage()` does not support.

There is an open issue about preloading images that suggests loading images without a BuildContext is not currently supported.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26127

Comment: if you want to cache images inside `initState` then you have `BuildContext` - it is `State.context` property, so create a method like: `precache() async {
    await precacheImage(AssetImage('images/bg.jpg'), context);
    print('precacheImage done');
  }` and use it inside`initState` by calling `Future(precache);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two workarounds, first one is initstate "delayed" like so :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) {
      //Your code here
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Second way is to use didChangeDependencies like so :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var image;

  bool init = true;  

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (init) {
      init = false;
      //your code here
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

init boolean is to prevent didChangeDependecies from running same code so many time as it reruns alot

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Preloading images is a problem I've been running into for years. Preload/precache is definitely an issue that is not yet solved. I'm going to keep this question open to see if anyone else has any more ideas.