# Why does it show Black screen instead of background image after login in flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I am working on a small app with a login page and a landing page where I want to display a background. On first login, it shows black screen but when I comment this line, it displays red error screen After I remove the commenting, and do Hot reload, it displays the error. When I logout and login again, the whole scenario repeats. Am I missing something? background image works fine for the login page though. I've tried wipe-data and restart emulator as well but to no avail.

```
// main.dart

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sewer Viewer',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.shade200, //0xff7c94b6
          image: DecorationImage(

// On first login, it shows black screen but when I comment this line, it displays red error screen
// After I remove the commenting, and do Hot reload, it displays the error.
// When I logout and login again, the whole scenario repeats

            image: AssetImage("images/bg.jpg"), 
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.green.withOpacity(0.5), BlendMode.dstIn),
          ),
        ),
        child: MainPage(),
      ),
      theme: ThemeData(
        accentColor: Colors.white70,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          children: [
            Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
// login_page.dart
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  String _loginMessage = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkLoginMessages();
  }

  void checkLoginMessages() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (sharedPreferences.getString("login_message") != null) {
      setState(() {
        _loginMessage = sharedPreferences.getString("login_message");
      });
    } else {
      _loginMessage = "";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
              Colors.blue,
              Colors.teal,
            ], begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
          ),
          child: _isLoading
              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('images/bg.jpg'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )),
                    ),
                    ListView(
                      children: [
                        _headerSection(),
                        _formSection(),
                        _messageSection(),
                        _buttonSection(),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                )),
    );
  }

  signIn(String email, String password) async {
    //var jsonData = null;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String urlAPI =
        "<SOME_URL_HERE>";
    var body = {'email': email, 'password': password};
    var response = await http.post(urlAPI, body: body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
        sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonData['userToken']);
        print(response.body);
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainPage()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
        sharedPreferences.setString(
            "login_message", "Incorrect Username/Password");
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      });
      print(response.body);
    }
  }

  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Container _messageSection() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
      child: Text(
        _loginMessage,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow, fontSize: 14.0),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container _formSection() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
              primaryColor: Colors.orange.shade700,
            ),
            child: txtSection("Email", emailController, Icons.email),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30.0,
          ),
          Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
              primaryColor: Colors.orange.shade700,
            ),
            child: txtSection("Password", passwordController, Icons.lock),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget txtSection(
          String title, TextEditingController textController, IconData icon) =>
      TextFormField(
        controller: textController,
        obscureText: title != "Password" ? false : true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: title,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
          icon: Icon(icon),
        ),
      );

  Container _buttonSection() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 40.0,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      child: RaisedButton.icon(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _isLoading = true; // this will allow circularloader to be displayed
          });
          // start signin process
          signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
        },
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.add_to_home_screen,
          color: Colors.white70,
        ),
        color: Colors.green.shade700,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        label: Text(
          "Sign In",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container _headerSection() {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 30.0),
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
        child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'));
  }
}
```

Error Log

```
2020-08-28 04:26:48.688 348-348/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-08-28 04:26:48.688 348-348/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-08-28 04:26:48.734 177-182/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-08-28 04:26:48.746 177-182/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-08-28 04:26:48.896 361-361/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-08-28 04:26:48.896 361-361/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-08-28 04:26:53.619 177-182/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-08-28 04:26:53.629 177-182/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-08-28 04:27:08.722 177-182/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-08-28 04:27:08.738 177-182/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-08-28 04:27:13.626 177-182/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-08-28 04:27:13.639 177-182/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-08-28 04:27:28.695 177-182/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-08-28 04:27:28.704 177-182/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-08-28 04:27:33.642 177-182/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-08-28 04:27:33.652 177-182/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-08-28 04:27:48.656 177-182/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
```

[image: After Login]
[image: After commenting out the background image loading line]
[image: After de-commenting the line]

Comment: Can you share screenshots and error logs?

Comment: I've noticed something though. After login, for a second, it does display the background image, but then blackens. Secondly, I tried to record the screen in Android Studio but the video turns out to be fine. No black screen in it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it shows the black screen is since flutter needs time to load the assets, so it is preferred to pre-Cache the assets. Now this has been a problem for a lot of people when they usually face when they are creating custom splash screens and the asset is heavy

So I followed
this github issue [This one](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26127)
and stack overflow issues [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62478972/preload-image-without-buildcontext) and [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343735/flutter-image-preload)

So in your code convert the
`MyApp` into the stateful widget

There are two ways you can try both

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var backgroundImage;

  bool init = true;  

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (init) {
      init = false;
      //your code here
      backgroundImage = AssetImage('images/bg.jpg');
      await precacheImage(backgroundImage,context);

    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(); //Will be your MaterialApp here
  }
}
```

or

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var backgroundImage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) {
      //Your code here
      backgroundImage = AssetImage('images/bg.jpg');
      await precacheImage(backgroundImage,context);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();   //Will be your MaterialApp here
  }
}
```

And make change here

and change here

```
BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                        image: backgroundImage,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
```

Well everything I have mentioned is a workaround as the issue is still open so hope this works well.

Comment: the first solution doesn't give an error but doesn't give the desired result either. the second solution gave following error. ```'package:flutter/src/painting/decoration_image.dart': Failed assertion: line 56 pos 15: 'image != null': is not true.```